# Perl - Assign variables to values of references

Tags: arrays, perl, reference, dereference, assign

There is a similar question [How can I assign the result of a subroutine call to array references in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531003/how-can-i-assign-the-result-of-a-subroutine-call-to-array-references-in-perl) but I'm curious about perl's possibilities

Is there a hack in perl to directly dereference element-wise an array of references?

in a code like

```
sub test { return([1..4],[5..8]); }
my (@a,@b);
my @result = test();
@a = @{$result[0]}; @b = @{$result[1]};
```

I would like to shorten the code to a simple statement like

```
sub test { return([1..4],[5..8]); }
my (\@a,\@b) = test();
```

or in a loop

```
foreach my $element (\"1",\"2",\"3") {
    my $dereferenced_element = $$element;
```

it would be nice to write something like

```
foreach my \$element (\"1",\"2",\"3") {
```

I know that this syntax doesn't make much sense, as I don't want to assign a value to the reference of a variable, but to assign a dereferenced value to the variable itself
but I'm curious if there is anything in that direction in perl's repertoire and I think this example shows the best, what I'm intending to do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify the globes directly if you want, but that is not a good practice.

```
sub test { return [1..3], [2..4]; }
(*x, *y) = test;
print "@x and @y";
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 and 2 3 4
```

This doesn't work with lexical (`my`) variables. To make it work with `strict`, you can declare the variables with `our` (instead of `my`).

Comment: +1 this is a very nice possibility; if no answer is coming closer to what I want, I'll accept this as answer

Answer (score 2):

This is not answering your question regarding the direct de-referencing but

what you are doing in:

```
sub test { return([1..4],[5..8]); }
my (@a,@b);
my @result = test();
@a = $result[0]; @b = $result[1];
```

is not entirely correct, your @a and @b arrays become 2d arrays after this.

Instead you should say:

```
@a = @{$result[0]};
@b = @{$result[1]};
```

or, as you most probably already know:

```
my ($a, $b) = test();
```

or:

```
for my $element (test()) {
     # $element is an array ref
}
```

Comment: oh sorry you are absolutely correct; while typing I forgot to add the @{} thx

Answer (score 1):

@Qtax answer is neat. I was wondering else it could be done. Not exactly what you asked for, but near.

```
sub test { return [1..3], [2..4]; }

my (%a);

@a{'ret1','ret2'} = test();

print @{$a{'ret1'}} ;
print @{$a{'ret2'}} ;
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way, IMO, is to assign the array refs to scalar variables, and dereference them as needed.

```
my ($x, $y) = test();

my @arrayx = @$x;
my @arrayy = @$y;

print "Element 1 in \$x is: $x->[1]\n";
for my $element (@$x) { ... }
```

You should also be aware that using `$a` and `$b` as variables is a bad idea, because they are predefined global variables used by the `sort` routine. They *can* be used, like most predefined variables, but it may lead to strange behaviour and hard to find bugs.

Comment: I agree that this is the most reasonable way, but I was curious about the possibilities; $a,$b here are just for an example; in practice I use speaking names

Comment: @Hachi There is no mystery here. You are returning a list of two scalar arguments. You can assign them to scalars or dereference them into arrays. That's it. The global solution with `*a` relies on bending the rules, and is not really much different than using an intermediate scalar `$x = test(); @x = @$x`. Using global values is not something I'd recommend in order to save yourself some typing.